# Python tkinter destroy window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a beginner to python and I'm trying to do a little thing for my self but couldn't figure out how to destroy the first window after clicking the button and opening the new window,and it will keep the variables entered in first window for second window right ?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys
def showdata():
    email1 = email.get()
    password2 = password1.get()
    print(email1 +" "+ password2)
    exec(open("scratch.py").read())


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("CANmail")
window.geometry("300x150")
em = Label(window, text="E-mail").place(relx=0.2,rely=0.2)

pd = Label(window, text="Password").place(relx=0.2,rely=0.4)

email = Entry(window)
password1 = Entry(window)

email.grid(row=0, column=1)
email.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.2)
password1.grid(row=1, column=1)
password1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.4)

btn = Button(window, text="Log In", command=showdata)
btn.grid(row=2, column=1)
btn.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.7,anchor=CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click button and call show data function call function:

```
def quit(window):
    window.destroy()
```

it think it gonna help you.
Here another example:

```
import tkinter


class App():
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
       button = Tkinter.Button(self.root, text = 'root quit', command=self.quit)
       button.pack()
       self.root.mainloop()

   def quit(self):
       self.root.destroy()

app = App()
```

Comment: i did a mistake in the one i shared because there i wanted to see if i can get the value so now i added 
def quit(window):
    exec(open("scratch.py").read())
    window.destroy()
after mainloop() but it only closes the window,doesnt open the scratch.py i need it to close,open scratch.py with the variable entered saved there when i get the value from the first file

Comment: if you want it. you need first open scratch.py and after close window

Comment: like how,i tried to put exec(open("scratch.py").read()) first but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found by practice how to do it by just adding the `window.destroy()` command to the other file's beginning since it needs to be written after the loop of the first file

Answer (score 0):

You could save your variables from the first window and just use them in another window.

Why just not use the **import** from scratch.py like this? and pass variables to there this way:

**scratch.py file**:

```py
def customize_window(customer_email,customer_password):
    w = Tk()
    w.geometry('300x150')
    l1 = Label(w,text = 'Your Email is:{0}'.format(customer_email))
    l2 = Label(w,text = 'Your Password is:{0}'.format(customer_password))
    l1.pack()
    l2.pack()
    w.mainloop()
```

And then go to your main file and do this:

```
from .scratch import customize_window
##your code...
...
...
root.destroy()

customize_window(customer_email = email.get(), customer_password = password1.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Frame` for the login window and hide it after a successful login (in `showdata` function) then show another one for the main window and if you use a class your do not need to pass the variables, they will be accessible using `self.`

Try the following example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button, Toplevel


class MyApp(object):
    """"""


    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")
        self.frame = Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        Label(self.frame).grid(row=0,column=0) # Add a space between top border and E-mail widget

        self.em = Label(self.frame, text="E-mail")
        self.em.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.pd = Label(self.frame, text="Password")
        self.pd.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.email = Entry(self.frame)
        self.password1 = Entry(self.frame)

        self.email.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.password1.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.btn = Button(self.frame, text="Log In", command=self.showdata)
        self.btn.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def hide(self):

        self.root.withdraw()

    def openFrame(self):
        self.hide()
        otherFrame = Toplevel()
        otherFrame.geometry("400x300")
        otherFrame.title("otherFrame")
        handler = lambda: self.onCloseOtherFrame(otherFrame)
        btn = Button(otherFrame, text="Close", command=handler)
        btn.pack()

    def onCloseOtherFrame(self, otherFrame):
        otherFrame.destroy()
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

    def showdata(self):
        email1 = self.email.get()
        password2 = self.password1.get()
        print(email1 +" "+ password2)

        # exec(open("scratch.py").read())
        self.openFrame()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x100")
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```